# How can I properly mock a function which uses a pointer receiver to a struct?

Tags: go, testing, mocking

Imagine I have a `Client` struct to hold some dependencies

```golang
type Client struct {
   httpClient *http.Client
   config *Config
}
```

and I have a function which uses a pointer receiver to this struct and performs an http call

```golang
func (client *Client) Get() (*Response, error) {
  ...
  client.httpClient.get(url)
}
```

My conundrum here is that I feel like I can not mock something which is not passed into the function as a parameter, but passed via being accessible by *Client pointer receiver.

What would be the best approach to be able to mock the underlying httpClient output?

Tried to use interfaces but I got a bit confused with the embedded dependencies

Comment: Why do you wan't to mock anything here? Just set up a Client suitable for your test (i.e. set up config and a suitable httpClient) and call Get on it. You probably want to use an url that points to some fake HTTP server run via net/http/httptest.Server. All this "mocking" doesn't work well in Go (and is bad in other languages too albeit it's the only solution there).

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best approach to be able to mock the underlying httpClient output?

Don't mock it at all. Use a proper net/http.Client and make an *actual* HTTP call.

Use a test server as target, e.g. start one with net/http/httptest.NewServer and use a fake handler that provides a suitable test response.